# Rendering polygon as graph with directed edges in Mathematica

Tags: graphs-and-networks

In Mathematica I'm trying to render a polygon as a set of vertices and directed edges.

What I have so far:

```
Graphics[Polygon[{{1, 10}, {2, 4}, {10, 5}, {20, 10}}]]
```

I see Mathematica has the `Graph` and `PathGraph` commands - both of which have a `DirectedEdges` option - but it seems like I have no control over the position of the vertices with these commands.

If I could customize the fill and edge/stroke of the `Polygon` command, that would be acceptable - but I'm not seeing how to do it. It looks like this command is specifically meant to draw filled polygons.

I'd also be OK with a custom Mathematica routine to draw what I want using a loop and multiple `Line` commands within a `Graphics` command - but I can't see how to draw the lines as arrows (I'm sure I could make the routine do this with *three* `Line`s per edge, but I really just think I'm missing something here.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Graph` has the option `VertexCoordinates` which allows you to specify the coordinates of the vertices, so you could do something like

```
crds = {{1, 10}, {2, 4}, {10, 5}, {20, 10}};
vertices = Range[Length[crds]];
edges = Thread[vertices \[DirectedEdge] RotateLeft[vertices]];

Graph[vertices, edges, VertexCoordinates -> crds,
 EdgeShapeFunction -> GraphElementData[{"Arrow", "ArrowSize" -> .1}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can also use `Graphics` primitives, for example

```
edges1 = Thread[{crds, RotateLeft[crds]}];

Graphics[{Red, Arrow /@ edges1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Loving the new Mathematica SE site! That's awesome... thank you very much. Just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

```
n = 5;
Graphics@Arrow@Table[{Sin[2 Pi i/n], Cos[2 Pi i/n]}, {i, 1, n + 1}]
```

[image]

**Edit**

```
GraphicsGrid[Partition[
  Table[Graphics@
    Arrow@Partition[Table[{Sin[2 Pi i/j], Cos[2 Pi i/j]}, {i, 1, j + 1}], 2, 1], 
   {j,3, 12}], 3], Frame -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Two good answers... but I had to pick one. I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 4):

You had this already

```
pol = Graphics[Polygon[{{1, 10}, {2, 4}, {10, 5}, {20, 10}}]];
```

You can turn it into something similar to what you want with

```
pol /. Polygon[i_] :> Thread@Arrow@Partition[i, 2, 1, 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: +1 Very nice! Thank you!