# Converting polygon to graph in V7

Tags: graphs-and-networks, version-7

I've unsuccessfully tried many ways of converting polygon points into a graph using *Mathematica* 7,  and I am frustrated.  I looked at [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6161/rendering-polygon-as-graph-with-directed-edges-in-mathematica), but it doesn't work:

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"];
crds = {{1, 10}, {2, 4}, {10, 5}, {20, 10}};
vertices = Range[Length[crds]];
edges = Thread[vertices \[DirectedEdge] RotateLeft[vertices]];

Graph[vertices, edges]
```

produces errors:

```
Syntax::sntxf: "\!\(\*StyleBox[\"\\\"\\\\\\\"\\\"\", \"MT\"]\)\!\(\*StyleBox[\!
\(vertices\), \"MT\"]\)\!\(\*StyleBox[\"\\\"\\\\\\\" cannot be followed by \\\\\\\"
\\\"\", \"MT\"]\)\!\(\*StyleBox[\!\(\(\(\\[ DirectedEdge]\)\) \(\(RotateLeft[vertices]
\)\)\), \"MT\"]\)\!\(\*StyleBox[\"\\\"\\\\\\\".\\\"\", \"MT\"]\)\!\(\*StyleBox[\!
\(\"\"\), \"MT\"]\)"

Syntax::tsntxi: "\!\(\*StyleBox[\"\\\"\\\\\\\"\\\"\", \"MT\"]\)\!\(\*StyleBox[\!\(\\[ 
DirectedEdge]\), \"MT\"]\)\!\(\*StyleBox[\"\\\"\\\\\\\" is incomplete; more input is 
needed.\\\"\", \"MT\"]\)\!\(\*StyleBox[\!\(\"\"\), \"MT\"]\)"

Syntax::sntxi: Incomplete expression; more input is needed.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The syntax of Graph in Combinatorica is `Graph[e, v, opts]`, not `Graph[v, e]` as with the new built-in Graph.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Combinatorica, you should usually use MakeGraph rather than Graph directly. Here are some expressions that create the graph you want and which can be easily adapted for use with any graph that you've defined appropriate `vertices` and `edges` symbols for:

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"]
crds = {{1, 10}, {2, 4}, {10, 5}, {20, 10}};
vertices = Range[Length[crds]];
edges = Thread[vertices -> RotateLeft[vertices]];
g = MakeGraph[vertices, MemberQ[edges, #1 -> #2] &]
ShowGraph@g
```

Comment: same errors as above

Comment: @jnthn: Interesting, I think I missed the errors because I was working in 9.0.1. My apologies, as I did have access to 7.0 for testing. Glad that I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"];
crds = {{1, 10}, {2, 4}, {10, 5}, {20, 10}}
vertices = Range[Length[crds]]; edges = 
Thread[vertices -> RotateLeft[vertices]];
GraphPlot[edges]
```

Comment: In[]:= Head[GraphPlot[e] Out[]:= Graphics, so it is not a graph.  I cant use Degrees[] on it.